# generating thumbnails for 8000+ images

Tags: php, gd

A while back me and some of my friends set down and created our own file hosting/sharing service which we use internally (privately). This is not a public server or what not as its solely designed for our use.

The entire thing is hosted on following specs.

- Processor:  AMD Phenom II X4 (Model: 955) @ 3.20 Ghz
- RAM:        8 GB's
- OS:         Windows Vista Home Premium @ 64 Bit
- HDD:        x2 1 TB SATA

It takes a bit to working with the files not to mention the php.ini had to be rewriten quite a bit allowing nearly 1 GB of memory to be dedicated to script and extending execution time to 400 sec.

**QUESTION:
 So the specs are good enough to handle the load but is there a better way to optimize the code provided below to allow it to run through 8000+ images and not lag the system a lot? Not to mention stopping after going through 500+ files.**

And here is the code for the actual script.

```
function make_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width) {
  /* read the source image */
  $de_width = 100;
  $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
  $width = imagesx($source_image);
  $height = imagesy($source_image);
  /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
  $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
  /* create a new, "virtual" image */
  $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);
  /* copy source image at a resized size */
  imagecopyresampled($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
  /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
  imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest,75);
}

function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg')) {
  $files = array();
  if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
      if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
        $files[] = $file;
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
  return $files;
}

/* function:  returns a file's extension */
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
  return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}

$images_dir = 'data/'.$key.'/photos/';
$thumbs_dir = 'data/'.$key.'/photos/f/';
$thumbs_width = 100;
$images_per_row = 6;

/** generate photo gallery **/
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
if(count($image_files)) {
  $index = 0;
  foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
    $index++;
    $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
    if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
      $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
      if($extension) {
        fm_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width);
      }
    }
    echo '<a href="',$images_dir.$file,'" rel="gallery"><img src="',$thumbnail_image,'" class="photo-link"/></a>';
    if($index % $images_per_row == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
  }
  echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
else {
  echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
}
```

Comment: sry about that re-refer to question

Comment: I'd just try installing ImageMagick and call it from the command line via PHP.

Comment: If it is an internal server why do you care so much about the lag?  Also, it might stop after ~500 images because 400 sec is not enough time to process your request?  Why not set the time limit to unlimited at first to see how long it actually takes?

Comment: Have you looked at imagedestroy? For freeing memory in between images

Comment: @afuzzyllama I don't quietly care since that machine aint used by any one its dedicated to store about it, but the lag on it can be a bit annoying. Since the client-side gets lagged as well, as the files for each user are displayed via web panel. #ontrack actually no I have not though of that, huh forgot about image destroy

Answer (score 0):

You can use and ImageProcessor that you can install on your server, or write one in any compiled languages, it will be faster than php, and you can limit the resource usage depending on the application you use.

You can use `shell_exec('console command here')` to do the process.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php